# ssh to another user of the same host using dns domain

Tags: ssh, hostname, key-authentication

Is it a problem to ssh to another user of the same host using dns domain? I cannot conigure it. I cannot configure it to passwordless connection. Also when I am trying to connect with password the message I am gtting is `Permission denied, please try again.`

It is being possible to connect  with `localhost` as domain, but then the terminal output is without the prompting.

### destination user

```
deployer@stretch:~$ ls ~/.ssh/
authorized_keys
deployer@stretch:~$ ls -l ~/.ssh/authorized_keys 
-rw------- 1 deployer deployer 403 Aug 15 17:31 /home/deployer/.ssh/authorized_keys
deployer@stretch:~$ namei -mo   /home/deployer/.ssh/authorized_keys 
f: /home/deployer/.ssh/authorized_keys
 drwxr-xr-x root     root     /
 drwxr-xr-x root     root     home
 drwxr-xr-x deployer deployer deployer
 drwx------ deployer deployer .ssh
 -rw------- deployer deployer authorized_keys
deployer@stretch:~$
```

### user who put ssh command

```
gitlab-runner@stretch:~$ ls ~/.ssh/
id_rsa  id_rsa.pub  known_hosts
gitlab-runner@stretch:~$ ls -l ~/.ssh/id_rsa
-rw------- 1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner 1675 Aug 15 17:31 /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_rsa
gitlab-runner@stretch:~$ namei -mo   /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_rsa
f: /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_rsa
 drwxr-xr-x root          root          /
 drwxr-xr-x root          root          home
 drwxr-xr-x gitlab-runner gitlab-runner gitlab-runner
 drwx------ gitlab-runner gitlab-runner .ssh
 -rw------- gitlab-runner gitlab-runner id_rsa
gitlab-runner@stretch:~$
```

### ssh command that fails

```
gitlab-runner@stretch:~$ ssh -Tvvv  deployer@mydomain283.com
OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u3, OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "mydomain283.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to mydomain283.com [12.123.123.123] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to mydomain283.com:22 as 'deployer'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from mydomain283.com
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:mYi0FPiwWAkLr89mCOjL/5NrcpoXhAc+U/qlZ3Vo5Aw
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from mydomain283.com
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 12.123.123.123
debug1: Host 'mydomain283.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_rsa (0x55bbf13f3c80)
debug2: key: /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
deployer@mydomain283.com's password: 
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
deployer@mydomain283.com's password:
```

### ssh command to localhost

```
gitlab-runner@stretch:~$ ssh -Tvvv  deployer@localhost
OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u3, OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "localhost" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to localhost:22 as 'deployer'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from localhost
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:VAyOSIW0LSfaRmkWjUVNoXVK1pfSClohu+gtdFoYV4Y
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from localhost
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_rsa (0x55fee1c6ab90)
debug2: key: /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:E3fCKfzIiv4djAtFYQthmIX/k8u4mh/xnGhD3IIYzN4
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:E3fCKfzIiv4djAtFYQthmIX/k8u4mh/xnGhD3IIYzN4
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to localhost ([::1]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IPV6_TCLASS 0x08
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CONNECTION
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env OLDPWD
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CLIENT
debug3: Ignored env SSH_TTY
debug3: Ignored env MAIL
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Linux stretch 4.9.0-7-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-1 (2018-07-05) x86_64

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
ls
var
pwd
/home/deployer
whoami
deployer
```

### Update

### Some config data

```
root@stretch:/home# cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config |grep -i passw
# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no
# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
root@stretch:/home#
```

And I am able to ssh without password from my home machine.

Comment: _Permission denied, please try again_ maybe raise of the wrong password. could you confirm: 1- your password correct? 2-ssh service on destination machine allows to setup ssh-passless?

Comment: Password is correct. Tried 20 times and logged from another user. I don't know all sshd config settings meaning but I grep those with `pass`. Updated question.

Comment: And I am able to ssh without password from my home machine.

Comment: `mydomain283.com` is resolving to a different machine than the localhost.  You can see this since localhost is running ssh version `OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u3` while the machine you reach when you try to connect to `mydomain283.com` is running `OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4`.  Try `dig +short -t a mydomain283.com` to see what machine you are actually trying to connect to with that command--most likely a NAT'ing router.

Comment: does your home machine have static IP?

Comment: The domain and ip in the question are fake to keep them private. Sorry. Home machine has not static IP. But the problem is located on VPS. Both users are on VPS in the same debian instance.

Comment: Nonetheless, the comment from @user4556274 is correct. You are not talking with the same `sshd` servers.

Comment: Yes You are right. So I am now closer to resolve the problem. In fact gitlab runner is a virtual machine. So it is like we must consider another host. My research is about to configure gitlab deployment and I have just found a better way to achieve it. I am leaving that gitlab-runner user.